# how to draw fixed string on pictureBox using C#?

Tags: c#, picturebox, drawstring

I have to draw some text on pictureBox image (Gray scale image). I got some codes. its working but its moving with the image while panning and zooming, and it disappear while changing the window level.

```
            rect = pictureBox1.ClientRectangle;
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
            Font f = new Font("Arial", 15);
            g.DrawString("Murugesan", f, brush, start);
```

I want the text in the permanent location and it never disappear while changing the window level. Anybody there to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should draw it on `PictureBox` `OnPaint` event and use e.Graphics.

Probably you wouldn't have artifacts you mentioned if you used:

```
Graphics g = pictureBox.CreateGraphics();
```

But paint on event is still better than that.